# Alternative to epoll_wait, which does not wait for file descriptor?

Tags: c, linux, file, epoll

I have a program which creates a timer using timerfd_create (the timer when it expires, sets a file descriptor).

Problem is, i am using `epoll_wait` to wait for the file descriptor, then checking for the expiration using `fd=revent.data.fd` and `fd=timer_fd` (see program below).

But if i do this, `epoll_wait` blocks my program till timer expires, and i don't want this to happen..i want the program to run, and periodically i will check for timer expire. Is there any alternative approach to that?

Please see the program below.

```
enter code here
#include <sys/timerfd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
  struct itimerspec its;
  struct epoll_event event, revent;

  int timer_fd, efd, fd1, fd2;

 /* Setting timer interval */

 its.it_interval.tv_sec=1;
 its.it_interval.tv_nsec=0;

 /* Setting timer expiration */

 its.it_value.tv_sec=5;
 its.it_value.tv_nsec=0;

 efd=epoll_create(2);

 timer_fd=timerfd_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, TFD_NONBLOCK);

 event.data.fd=timer_fd;
 event.events=EPOLLIN|EPOLLPRI;
 epoll_ctl(efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, timer_fd, &event);

 if(timer_fd==-1)
 {
  fprintf(stderr,"timerfd_settime error:");
  exit;
 }

if(timerfd_settime(timer_fd, 0, &its, NULL)==-1)
{
 fprintf(stderr,"timerfd_settime error:");
 exit;
}

printf("Starting the timer...");
fd1=epoll_wait(efd, &revent, 1, -1);

if(fd1<0) {
 fprintf(stderr, "epoll_wait error\n");
 exit;
}
else {

fprintf(stdout, "number of fds: %d",fd1);
}

fd2=revent.data.fd;

if(fd2==timer_fd) {
 printf("Timer expired\n");  

// IMPORTANT: This i want to check periodically without epoll_wait which blocks the program, What is the alternative?
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of polling with epoll, since you're only waiting on one timer you can just check if it's expired by `read`ing it. The number of times it  has expired will then be stored in the buffer that you're `read`ing into, or if it hasn't expired, the `read` will fail with the error EAGAIN.

```
// set up timer
// ... 

uint64_t expirations;
if ((read(timer_fd, &expirations, sizeof(uint64_t))==-1) && errno == EAGAIN) {
  printf("Timer has not expired yet.\n");
} else {
  printf("Timer has expired %llu times.\n", expirations);
}
```

Note that you'll need to initialize `timer_fd` with the flag `TFD_NONBLOCK`, or else the `read` will block if it hasn't expired yet rather than fail, but you already do that.

Comment: @Sean: Why uint64_t? Can't we directly use int?

Comment: It gives an error `timerfd1.c:59: error: 'for' loop initial declaration used outside C99 mode`

Comment: No, actually. Reading from a timer_fd is very picky -- it'll fail with the error EINVAL in any case if you give it a buffer of less than 8 bytes.

Comment: I didn't test the code I posted so it might not work as-is, but the error you posted doesn't seem to be from this. Do you have something such as `for(int i = 0; i < n, i++)` anywhere? In good old-fashioned C you can't do that, you have to do `int i; for (i = 0; i < n; i++)`

Comment: @Sean: Ohh yes, thanks a lot...the same was the reason..also your code worked, thank you so much :)

Comment: Nice! No problem. I came back here to change the read==-1 thing but saw you already did it :)

Comment: Thanks :) yes, that's how i used it in the code, so thought to put it in yours too for others benefit :)

Answer (score 1):

This seems quite backwards. The reason why timerfd was created in the first place was to allow polling a fd for timer completions instead of using signals/threads/{no notification} as the normal timer_create interface allows you. If you don't want to poll on a fd, don't use timerfd_create!

So if you want to periodically poll your timer yourself, just use timer_create() to create a timer with SIGEV_NONE, and then use timer_gettime() to check it manually.